# How to set locale in kotlin's decimal format

Tags: android, kotlin, double, decimalformat

I use kotlin's decimal format and when my input is 15.4, my phone shows 15.4 instead of 15.4. But in the virtual machine on the computer, it still displays 15.4 correctly. I think this is a locale problem, can anyone help me?

Here is my code:
val formatter = DecimalFormat("##0.######")
return formatter.format(value)

I need the following result:
15.4 ->> 15.4
But I got the result:
15.4 ->> 15,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should use [DecimalFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) to format with the period.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US)
  val formatter = DecimalFormat("##0.######", symbols)
  println(formatter.format(15.4)) // should be 15.4
}
```